# 'MvvmCross.HotTuna.CrossCore' already has a dependency defined for 'MvvmCross.HotTuna.Binding'

Tags: android, xamarin, google-play-services, mvvmcross

When i am trying to install Google play service base and Google play service plus, i get this error:

```
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : 'MvvmCross.HotTuna.CrossCore' already has a dependency defined for 'MvvmCross.HotTuna.Binding'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base -Pre
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Answer (score 1):

did you try a nuget recovery using the command-line after updating nuget to the latest version (nuget update -self)

Comment: You indeed need an update for Nuget. Read more about this issue here: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/1088